# How can I find a div with “dhx_cal_light” class and change its style height to 460px

Tags: jquery

How can I find a div with “dhx_cal_light” class and change its style height to 460px.

My HTML:

```
<div class="dhx_cal_light" style="visibility: visible; height: 511px; display: block; top: 80px; left: 633px;">
```

My Code I tried:

```
$('div').find('dhx_cal_light').height('460');
```

Comment: almost - `$('div').find('.dhx_cal_light').css('height':'460');` or `$('div.dhx_cal_light').height('460');`

Comment: Thats right put DOT(.) for class selector in find('.dhx_cal_light').

Comment: Thank you all for your help. yes I missed the dot. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.dhx_cal_light").height('460');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `dhx_cal_light`  is a class , You missed class selector  `.`

```
$('div').find('.dhx_cal_light').height('460');
---------------^
```